# How do I use Request.UrlReferrer with my HTTPS site?

Tags: asp.net

I am using `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the previous link, but it is not working for my HTTPS site. I can't use the query string; Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the referrerUrl if comming from encrypted site (with SSL fx). The referrer header is pretty insecure, one can simply hit your URL and pass up any referer they want.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol.

Comment: So is there any way to find the previous page URL?